# How to get more appropriate Places icon from search

Tags: google-places-api

I am doing a specific search for "types=cafe" and "keyword=Coffee%20Shops" and the icon returned for most establishments is the "restaurant" (fork and spoon) icon.  Is there a way to format the request to receive the "cafe" icon, which is a coffee cup image?  This is the url search string:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=42.25850666666667,-87.94816&sensor=false&rankby=distance&keyword=Coffee%20Shops&types=cafe&key=mykey

Answer (score 0):

I have reported this as a bug and it should be fixed asap.

In the mean time you could just use http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/cafe-71.png for any place that has type `cafe`.

Answer (score 0):

when does the bug that return more types or other types will be fixed, this is critical

i.e: 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=42.25850666666667,-87.94816&sensor=false&rankby=distance&types=cafe&key=mykey

return other types like "store", "cafe", "food", "establishment" 
why not only cafe
if i wanted more i should ask for more like types=cafe|store..

thank you.